# ODP.Net 1.1 client doesnot work on machine with oracle 11g

Tags: odp.net, assembly-resolution

I have created an application that uses Oracle.Dataaccess library version 1.10. 
When I deploy the application on a machine that has 11g client i.e. Oracle.Dataaccess library 2.0 then this does not work. I get a message "Cannot find library Oracle.Dataaccess ver 1.10"

I am not sure what is wrong. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Currently we have 2 kinds of users. some are using ODP 1.1 and other 2.0. In this case redirection might not work for users with 1.1 right ?

Answer (score 0):

When using signed .NET assemblies, the correct version to use is essential. If you need to access Assembly version `y` with an assembly compiled against version `x`, use an [Assembly redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fc472t2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).